# ReactionCommerce: Unable to access MongoDB from shell

Tags: mongodb, meteor, e-commerce

I started ReactionCommerce using the command "meteor" and it started everything perfectly. I can access the web app and login into Admin view as well.

> [[[[[ ~\d\projects\reaction ]]]]]
>
> => Started proxy.
>   => Started MongoDB. 
> I20151228-18:22:26.026(5.5)? 12:52:25.432Z  INFO core: JobServer started: true
>   => Started your app.
>
> => App running at: http://localhost:3000/    
> Type Control-C twice to stop.
>
> I20151228-18:22:26.399(5.5)? 12:52:25.440Z  INFO core: Modified 0
>   documents while importing 19 to Translations
>   I20151228-18:22:26.400(5.5)? 12:52:25.441Z  INFO core: Modified 0
>   documents while importing 1 to Shops 
> I20151228-18:22:26.400(5.5)?
>   12:52:25.442Z  INFO core: Modified 0 documents while importing 1 to
>   Products 
> I20151228-18:22:26.401(5.5)? 12:52:25.443Z  INFO core:
>   Modified 0 documents while importing 2 to Tags
>   I20151228-18:22:26.401(5.5)? 12:52:25.444Z  INFO core: Reaction
>   initialization finished. 
> I20151228-18:22:26.401(5.5)? 12:52:25.585Z 
>   INFO core: Modified 1 document while importing 1 to Shipping

But, I am not able to connect to MongoDB (using RoboMongo) and I don't even see 27017 in LISTENING mode when I do a netstat.

I am on Windows.

To troubleshoot the problem, I installed a standalone MongoDB on another Linux box. I am able to successfully connect to this external instance without any problem.

The internals of how ReactionCommerce is managing MongoDB is not clear to me. I am new to both MongoDB and ReactionCommerce. I looked at other SO posts of similar problems, but they did not appear to be related to my issue.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the answer here: https://github.com/reactioncommerce/reaction/issues/625

Just issue: `meteor mongo` and you are done or connect to the DB on port 3001 instead of the default 27017.